# lxml etree.parse.xpath() returns items consiting of just tabs and newlines

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

For a typical eBay search results page such as [this](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?rt=nc&LH_Complete=1&_nkw=Mizuno%20Pants%20Belted%20Padded&LH_Sold=1&_sacat=0&LH_BIN=1&_from=R40&_sop=3&LH_ItemCondition=1000), I'm using lxml to extract the price of each result thus:

```
import urllib2
from lxml import etree

url =  "http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?rt=nc&LH_Complete=1&_nkw=Mizuno+Pants+Baseball&LH_Sold=1&_sacat=0&LH_BIN=1&_from=R40&_sop=3&LH_ItemCondition=1000"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
htmlparser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(response, htmlparser)
xpathselector="//span[@class ='bold bidsold']/text()"
tree.xpath(xpathselector)
```

While there are **50** search results (and therefore prices), tree.xpath(xpathselector) returns a list of length **100**, containing all of the prices but also containing items consisting of nothing but newlines and tabs (ignore the price difference in these results from those on the webpage - this is due to my geographic location). Why is this?

```
['\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 u' 1\xc2\xa0049.27',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 965.31',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 883.56',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 827.21',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 827.21',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 827.21',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 827.21',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 800.97',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 799.59',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 716.73',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 716.73',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 716.73',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 690.22',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 662.60',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 662.60',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 635.25',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 606.25',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 606.25',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 552.39',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 552.39',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 552.39',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 552.39',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 551.01',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 551.01',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 517.59',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 497.16',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 496.88',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 496.88',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 496.60',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 469.26',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 468.15',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 414.30',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 414.02',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 414.02',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 414.02',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 414.02',
 '\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 ' 386.68']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newlines and other whitespaces located directly within the target `span` are also text nodes, hence it get selected by `span[...]/text()` selector in your xpath. You can use xpath `normalize-space()` function in predicate to filter out empty text nodes though :

```
xpathselector="//span[@class ='bold bidsold']/text()[normalize-space()]"
```

**output :**

> ['506,533.33', '506,000.00', '466,000.00', '399,333.33', '399,333.33', '399,333.33', '399,333.33', '399,333.33', '386,666.67', '386,000.00', '346,000.00', '346,000.00', '346,000.00', '333,200.00', '333,200.00', '333,066.67', '319,866.67', '319,866.67', '306,666.67', '293,066.67', '292,666.67', '292,666.67', '266,666.67', '266,666.67', '266,666.67', '266,666.67', '266,533.33', '266,533.33', '266,533.33', '266,000.00', '266,000.00', '253,200.00', '249,866.67', '240,000.00', '239,866.67', '239,866.67', '239,733.33', '226,533.33']

Comment: Was not aware of the `normalize-space()` function. Thank you.